# How to display all labels on chart using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display data from a database table called ForecastTotal in a Windows Form.

In ForecastTotal, I have 37 rows and I want to display `Territory` in X axis and `UCPVol` in Y axis.

This is my database sample.

[image]

I tried this code.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from ForecastTotal ",conn);

try
{
    conn.Open();
    mydatareader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (mydatareader.Read())
    {
        //chart1.Series["UCP"].XValueMember = "Terriotry";
        //chart1.Series["UCP"].YValueMembers = "UCPVol";
        chart1.Series["UCP"].Points.AddXY(mydatareader.GetString(0), mydatareader.GetInt32(5));
        chart1.DataSource = forecastchart;
        chart1.DataBind();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The data source was 37 rows, but only 3 labels are shown on the chart.

[image]

How do I display the other labels?

Comment: the labels are probably loaded but not displayed. Try configure the chart so that label are oriented vertically and see if they appear. Also notice how the labels that ARE displayed are the one on the crossing lines.

Comment: You are mixing databinding and manually adding DataPoints. Why??? Also: Set the xaxis.interval to 1!

Comment: @Etienne ty .. but can u tell me how to configure the chart or make it works dynamically ?

Comment: Try this: Delete `chart1.DataSource = forecastchart;   chart1.DataBind();` and add `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1; chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1`

Comment: thank u very much .. it's working .. can u add ur answer to accpet it :)